# Не скачиваются файлы на Heroku через Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Мне нужно что бы бот скачивал файл из ссылки. Я использую эту функцию:

```
def download(url, filename):
    get_response = requests.get(url,stream=True)
    file_name  = filename
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in get_response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
```

А затем я отправляю его пользователю, используя это:

```
with open(music, 'rb') as music_file:
    await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, music_file)
```

На моём компе все работает отлично. Но вот когда я запускаю бота на Heroku, то он постоянно выдаёт эту ошибку:

```
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: File must be non-empty
```

Я пытался добавлять задержки, пытался проверять скачался ли файл, но ничего не помогло. Может кто нибудь помочь?

(почему то chunk в любом случае пуст при скачивании. С чем это связано?)

Comment: А почему бы вам просто сразу его не отправить без сохранения? Я так понимаю `chunk` это сам файл, просто отправьте его. Как я знаю хероку не хранит в себе файлы, ему негде их хранить.

Comment: попробую сделать

Comment: Я использовал print(chunk) что бы понять вообще есть ли там что то. И когда я пытаюсь снова скачать, то он вообще пуст.

Comment: chunk пустой только на heroku. На моём основном пк всё нормально

Comment: а это `get_response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024)` что там